# Windows 8 Touch Multiselect for Gridview vs Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, gridview, windows-8

I have a windows 8 application that has both list views and grid views. I see the following behavior when multi-selecting items on touch screens:

Grid View: Swipe down on touch screen for selecting items

List view: Swipe left or right for selecting items

Is this the standard behavior? I could not find any documentation on this.

This is for a Windows 8 Store App.

Comment: WPF or Windows Store Apps?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether you were writing WPF or Windows Store Apps, but as always, MSDN is the place to look for documentation either way. For WPF, you have:

[ListView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[GridView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And for Windows Store Apps, you have:

[ListView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx)
[GridView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx)

If you can't find the information that you need there, then I imagine the next best thing would be to create a simple application without setting any extra properties on your controls and then just try swiping them and then *that* will be the default behaviour.